# How to create a shade effect in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, shadows

I want to create my own `beamer theme` and I've got the rough code for it.

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext,enumerate,charter}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
%\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{226, 245, 13}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{253,111,1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[inner color=blau] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \node[opacity=.6] at ([xshift=.05cm,yshift=1.03cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[red] at ([yshift=1cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[ora] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{it}Der Autor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                \node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.75cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
            \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
            \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
            \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}1};
            \draw[red,thick,yshift=.1cm] (-1,3) -- (7.7,3) node[near end,above,xshift=1cm,red] {\changefont{put}{m}{n}Der Titel};
%           \node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\color{black!85}\footnotesize\blindtext[1]}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                    \node[yshift=.26cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.6cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east)  {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
                \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
                \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
                \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}2};
                %\node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
            \begin{enumerate}[\tikz{\fill[white]circle(.13);\fill[red]circle(.1);}]
                \item \color{black!85}Hallo,
                \item Welt!
            \end{enumerate}
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can I achieve that

- The "shadow" effect (e.g. *Das Zeichnen mit TikZ*; the same text with lower opacity below) automaticly adjusts on the text above (in mean that there is no longer `xshift=…` needed)?

I know just some commands which changed this into a "theme", but I'm not experienced with the use of the `beamer` class, I just know the basics.

Comment: Thanks for asking separate questions. Can you please focus them on the actual question?

Comment: Just use relative positioning: `\node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) (ZWT){\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \node[below left=10pt of ZWT.south east,xslant=.6,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};` I think that Ti*k*Z got a bit confused with the anchors because of `yscale=-1`. Of course, I would not hard code "Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z".

Comment: @marmot: Could you please post it as a MWE (of course you will get my +1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node relative positioning is more tricky if one has special scale transformations such as `yscale=-1` or `xslant=...`. To see that more explicitly, just give the node "Zeichnen mit Ti*k*Z" (which is sort of an oxymoron because Ti*k*Z stands for "Ti*k*Z ist kein Zeichenprogramm) the name `TWZ` and place a node relative to it with

```
\node[below=0pt of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
```

[image]

OK, a bit far off, but this is simply due to the inner sep of *both* nodes. Subtracting them yields

```
\node[below=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep} of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
```

[image]

Next, switch on `xslant=.6,yscale=-1,`

```
\node[xslant=.6,yscale=-1,below=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep} of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
```

[image]

Crazy, now the node is *above* the `TWZ` node. Why? Simply because the distances have been subjected to the transformations. So we have to undo this with

```
\node[xslant=.6,yscale=-1,xshift=-1.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner
            ysep},below=2.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep} of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
```

[image]

I did not use `below=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}` because I wanted to have a small gap. Similar for the prefactor of `xshift`, which should in theory be `2*0.6=1.2`, but the node is slanted and we want it to be further left.

So the bottomline is that one can understand where all these shift come from, but in the end one still needs to manually adjust things a bit. One can partly avoid this by using the anchors, but they also change their meaning under the transformations, such that I am not sure if that will buy us much.

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext,enumerate,charter}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
%\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{226, 245, 13}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{253,111,1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[inner color=blau] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \node[opacity=.6] at ([xshift=.05cm,yshift=1.03cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[red] at ([yshift=1cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[ora] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{it}Der Autor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                \node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) (ZWT){\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
%                \node[xslant=.6,yscale=-1,below=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep} of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
%                \node[below=0pt of ZWT.south,xslant=.6,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                 \node[xslant=.6,yscale=-1,xshift=-1.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner
                ysep},below=2.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep} of ZWT.south,opacity=.4] {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
            \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
            \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
            \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}1};
            \draw[red,thick,yshift=.1cm] (-1,3) -- (7.7,3) node[near end,above,xshift=1cm,red] {\changefont{put}{m}{n}Der Titel};
%           \node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\color{black!85}\footnotesize\blindtext[1]}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                    \node[yshift=.26cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.6cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east)  {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
                \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
                \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
                \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}2};
                %\node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
            \begin{enumerate}[\tikz{\fill[white]circle(.13);\fill[red]circle(.1);}]
                \item \color{black!85}Hallo,
                \item Welt!
            \end{enumerate}
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```